# Branch points in layman terms?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, branch-points

Im really confused about what branch points are. I've read so many definitions but none of them make sense to me.

I do get what a multivalued function is (i think)!

So with the complex logarithm for example: $ log(z) = log|z| + i\theta $

I get that this is multivalued as $ \theta $ can be changed in multiples of $ 2\pi $.

But i don't understand what a branch point is and why $ 0 $ is a branch point of the complex logarithm?

Same with the square root function which is the two functions we were taught.

Any help would be appreciated!